# How to transfer faster Bluetooth data?

Tags: c#, winforms, bluetooth

I am using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth library in the Windows forms. Communication between devices is fine, but too slow (I get response after ~150 ms with BT 5.2). I think that the problem is with write command (GattCharacteristic.WriteValueAsync()), because the time from calling this command to his executing is more then 100 ms.

Code:

```
                var writer = new DataWriter();
                var startCommand = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textBox_write_rawData.Text);

                writer.WriteBytes(startCommand);

                time = DateTime.Now;
                Display("Start time: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                GattCommunicationStatus result = await chara.WriteValueAsync(writer.DetachBuffer());

                if (result == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
                {
                    Display("Message sent successfully!");
                    //time = DateTime.Now;
                    //Display("Start time: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());

                }
                else
                {
                    Display("Error encountered on writing to characteristic!");
                }
```

Is possible to speed it up?

Thank you for your response!

Comment: Providing your code is the only way you're going to get any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved. Connection interval in the slave device was long. Also write without response can speed it up.